# Get closest upper and lower numbers for a consecutive column from another table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, data-analysis

I have a table associating neuron ids to special points in time - which I'll call Table 1. Something similar to:

| neuron_id | t |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 765 |
| 1 | 37 |
| 1 | 68 |

From that, I need an efficient way to build a table like (which I'll call Table 2):

| neuron_id | t | t_lower | t_upper |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0 | 5 | 4 | 765 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0 | 764 | 4 | 765 |
| 0 | 765 | 765 | 765 |
| 0 | 766 | 765 | 10000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0 | 10000 | 10000 | 10000 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 37 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 36 | 0 | 37 |
| 1 | 37 | 37 | 37 |
| 1 | 38 | 37 | 68 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 67 | 37 | 68 |
| 1 | 68 | 68 | 68 |
| 1 | 69 | 68 | 10000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Explanation: neuron_id and t in Table 2 are consecutive integers ranging from 0 to 99 and from 0 to 9999, respectively, with all their combinations considered (i.e, neuron_id = 0 has 10k points of t associated to it).

The other 2 columns in Table 2 (t_lower and t_upper) are simply the closest t in Table 1, below and above, respectively, to the t in Table 2.

I found a non-efficient to do it using pandas, but this process seems so simple to me that it looks like there's an easy very simple solution. I need efficiency because, in this case, the final table has 100*10k rows in it, and I need to run this for some of these tables.

Although I used pandas, I could easily work with a SQL solution as well.

Here is my non-efficient solution, for clarification on the reasoning. In it, Table 1 is stored in a SQLITE file, and Table 2 is being built in initial_df:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def get_burst_time_limits(row):
  neuron_id, t = row
  query = lambda sign: f'''
  SELECT {'MAX' if sign=='<' else 'MIN'}(t)
  FROM LocalMaxima
  WHERE t {sign} {t} AND neuron_idx = {neuron_id}
  '''

  db_path = 'path/to_a/sqlite_file.db'

  con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
  cur = con.cursor()
  lower_limit = cur.execute(query('<')).fetchall()[0][0]
  upper_limit = cur.execute(query('>')).fetchall()[0][0]

  return [lower_limit, upper_limit]

initial_df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(np.arange(100),np.arange(10000))),columns=['neuron_id','t'])
initial_df = initial_df.apply(get_burst_time_limits, axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 1):

I got to a solution myself. Basically, I start building table 2 as in my previous solution:

`initial_df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(np.arange(100),np.arange(10000))),columns=['neuron_id','t'])`

Then I do a left join with Table 2 to the left and Table 1 to the right on neuron_id and t being equal, originating a Table 3. The joined t column from Table 1 in Table 3 is mostly filled with nulls, except where it was present in Table 1. I can use that column to build t_lower, using pandas.interpolate with method set as pad, or use it to build t_upper, with method set to pad.